# How to detect intersecting segments based on length of the segments

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

As part of a larger problem, I am trying to detect based on the distance matrix which segments intersect in the original 2D space that originated the matrix. I don´t have coordinates (lat/long, x/y or any other for the points).

As an example, on the image below, the answer to the question for the top graph would be: AD, BC. While for the bottom graph would be AC, BD.

The information that we have is just the distance matrix:

DISTANCE MATRIX TOP

$
\begin{align}
 && A && B && C && D \\
A&& 0 && 1 && 1 && \sqrt{2} \\
B&& 1 && 0 && \sqrt{2} && 1 \\
C&& 1 && \sqrt{2} && 0 && 1 \\
D&& \sqrt{2} && 1 && 1 && 0
\end{align}
$

DISTANCE MATRIX BOTTOM

$
\begin{align}
 && A && B && C && D \\
A&& 0 && 1 && 1 && \sqrt{2} \\
B&& 1 && 0 && \sqrt{2} && \sqrt{5} \\
C&& 1 && \sqrt{2} && 0 && 1 \\
D&& \sqrt{2} && \sqrt{5} && 1 && 0
\end{align}
$

[image]

I have tried so far to use the triangular inequality and some other (probably) naive geometric knowledge but I can´t figure out what conditions must be met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume that you know where $A,B,C,D$ are.  In this case, you can write $D$ uniquely in the form $\alpha_A A + \alpha_B B + \alpha_C C$, with $\alpha_A + \alpha_B + \alpha_C = 1$. The tuple $(\alpha_A,\alpha_B,\alpha_C)$ are called the [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $D$.  You can read off which of the segments $Dx$ ($x\in \{A,B,C\}$) cross a side of the triangle $ABC$ from the sign pattern of the barycentric coordinates.

It's not particularly difficult to find suitable coordinates either.  You can just assume that $A=(0,0)$, $B=(d(A,B),0)$, and $C$ is either intersection point of the appropriate circles around $A$ and $B$.  This will then uniquely determine $D$ by intersecting three circles.

Comment: For me personally,  OP's question and this answer has been particularly interesting. I would love to see a pseudo implementation. Do any exist off-the-shelf? If not,  I will undertake an attempt myself.

Comment: So, are the alphas vectors? Can you give an example of the sign patterns you refer?

Comment: The $\alpha$s are numbers.  How to get them is explained at the wikipedia link on barycentric coordinates.  The sign pattern is just which of the $\alpha$s are positive and which are negative.  (For example, all positive means inside the triangle $ABC$.  Generally speaking, $\alpha_A > 0$ means that $D$ is on the same side of the line through $BC$ as $A$, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Louis, now that I have a bit more time to look at the links I find it highly useful. Do you know of any implementations of this? Java, Python, R would be great. I accept your answer as Best.